# Win API Aligning text on a button

Tags: c++, winapi, button, text, center

Is there a way to center align the text inside a button both horizontally and vertically?

```
case WM_DRAWITEM:
        {
            LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT Item;
            Item = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

            SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateFont(17, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, "Arial Black"));

            FillRect(Item->hDC, &Item->rcItem, CreateSolidBrush(0xE0E0E0) );

            SetBkMode(Item->hDC, 0xE0E0E0);
            SetTextColor(Item->hDC, RGB(255,255,255));

            int len;
            len = GetWindowTextLength(Item->hwndItem);
            LPSTR lpBuff;
            lpBuff = new char[len+1];
            GetWindowTextA(Item->hwndItem, lpBuff, len+1);
            DrawTextA(Item->hDC, lpBuff, len, &Item->rcItem, DT_CENTER);
        }
    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the `DT_CENTER` flag to center the text horizontally. `DrawText()` also has `DT_VCENTER` and `DT_SINGLELINE` flags to center the text vertically.  Simply combine the flags together.

Also, you have resource and memory leaks.  You are leaking the `HFONT` from `CreateFont()`, the `HBRUSH` from `CreateSolidBrush()`, and the text buffer from `new[]`.  You need to free them all when you are done using them.

Try this:

```
case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT Item = reinterpret_cast<LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT>(lParam);

        HFONT hFont = CreateFont(17, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, TEXT("Arial Black"));
        HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT) SelectObject(Item->hDC, hFont);

        HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0xE0, 0xE0, 0xE0));
        FillRect(Item->hDC, &Item->rcItem, hBrush);
        DeleteObject(hBrush);

        SetBkMode(Item->hDC, TRANSPARENT); // <-- 0xE0E0E0 was not a valid mode value!
        SetTextColor(Item->hDC, RGB(255,255,255));

        int len = GetWindowTextLength(Item->hwndItem) + 1;
        LPTSTR lpBuff = new TCHAR[len];
        len = GetWindowText(Item->hwndItem, lpBuff, len);
        DrawText(Item->hDC, lpBuff, len, &Item->rcItem, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
        delete[] lpBuff;

        SelectObject(Item->hDC, hOldFont);
        DeleteObject(hFont);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: I tried the above, it doesn't center the text for some reason, this is how I'm initialising the button:  button = CreateWindow("BUTTON","Overview",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW, 0,0,200,50, hwnd , (HMENU) 1 , NULL, NULL);

Comment: My bad, I forgot the `DT_SINGLELINE` flag, too.  That is needed for `DT_VCENTER` to work. I updated my answer, and tested that it actually works.

Answer (score -1):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/button-styles

Probably need to use `BS_OWNERDRAW` to do what you're describing.

Comment: the OP has to already be doing that, or they wouldn't be getting `WM_DRAWITEM` messages for the button in the first place.